# setInterval in a while loop didnt work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm an old reader of stackoverflow but new member, and this is my first question :) I'm trying to write a game with HTML5 canvas. But setInterval didn't start in a while loop. My code:

```
var text = "Message";
var exit = 0;
while(exit==0)
{
drawLifeBar(100);
var balls = new Array();
var startInterval = setInterval(function() { intervalLoop(balls);},50);
text += "\nYour level: " + level;
alert(text);
}
```

I got many alert boxes (loop working), but could not get in to setInterval. And setInterval works when i cancel the while loop. Whats the wrong in this while loop?

PS: It is a simple drop-ball-game. Balls drop, if you catch, then you leveled up. If not, game over. It worked fine without while loop. With while loop, I'm trying to do this: if you catch enough ball, then level++, closeinterval and restart game (setInterval). If game over, then exit=true, closeinterval and end the game.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening? What is `intervalLoop`?

Comment: Get rid of the while loop, place the interval inside a function instead.

Comment: Part of Kevin's comment is because you'd be setting multiple intervals to execute and startInterval would only contain the id of the last interval set.  Side note: your code is *not* complete... exit is never set to non-zero.  While you may think you have provided sufficent code, the actual code is what you really need to provide... bugs exist sometimes in places we'd never think!

Comment: setInterval and intervalLoop function works fine without while loop. I'm changing exit variable in the intervalLoop function just before  clearInterval.

Comment: I have been seeing a lot of `new Array()` instead of `[]` lately.

Answer (score 0):

```
function funcName() {
    alert("test");
}

var func = funcName();
var run = setInterval("func",10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var exit = false;


function intervalLoop(balls) {

      if(exit === true) clearInterval('startInterval');

}
```

Comment: Interval should not be inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

I took some guesses at what you meant to do.

I named your function `nextLevel` since that what it really was.. and I had it start the `intervalLoop` -- which, in this context, really doesn't need to be set by an interval.

When `intervalLoop` finishes whatever it is doing, it should call `nextLevel` to advance.

At the very bottom I call `nextLevel` to start the whole process off.

```
var text = "Message";
var exit = 0;

function nextLevel() {
  drawLifeBar(100);
  var balls = new Array();
  var startInterval = setInterval(function() { intervalLoop(balls);},50);
  text += "\nYour level: " + level;
  alert(text);
} 

// Missing from the code, so making something up
function intervalLoop(balls) {
  // Do something! The user one, restart the main loop
  // User won! Give him the next level
  nextLevel();
}


// And start the whole process here
nextLevel();
```

Comment: Jeremy,you guess right about program but this solution didn't work. I try "clearInterval(startInterval);startGame();" but once I clear interval, it never start again. :(

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for any of us to really help you .. I was taking a guess at things...